# Image recognition using Harris algo features

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I am new in image processing, could you please help to use Harrise cornerner detection algorithm for image recognition.
I think to run Harrris algo in my sample image, detect its corners. Than run the same algo on main image, in which I am trying to identify the sample image. After compare the features in the main image with the features found in the sample image.
But I am not sure these features are coordinates or not, if Harris algo returned features are coordinates than what should I compare?
This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename_sign = 'E:/Documents/Python/sample.jpg'
filename_photo = 'E:/Documents/Python/main.jpg'

img_sign = cv2.imread(filename_sign)
gray_sign = cv2.cvtColor(img_sign,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray_sign = np.float32(gray)
dst_sign = cv2.cornerHarris(gray_sign,2,3,0.04)

img_photo = cv2.imread(filename_photo)
gray_photo= cv2.cvtColor(img_sign,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

gray_photo= np.float32(gray)
dst_photo= cv2.cornerHarris(gray_photo,2,3,0.04)
```

My questions are:
 
1)  Can I use this method to recognize sample image on another image 
2)  How to compare the dst_sign features with dst_photo?

Answer (score 1):

There are better alternatives to the Harris corner detector that are more efficient and may give better results. The ORB feature detector and descriptor developed by the opencv team is a good alternative.

The detector (with the `orb.detect()`) finds the features in the image. These are what you would call corners. You would then use calculate the descriptor using `orb.compute()` for these keypoints. These basically describe the features in terms of orientation, location, etc. You could then use these descriptors to find matches between images using, for example, the `cv2.BFMatcher()`

Here are very good tutorials that you can use:

ORB:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html

feature matching: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher

EDIT: IF you want to perform object detection, however, there are alternatives like using [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) or you can use machine learning techniques like the [HOG SVM](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/10/histogram-oriented-gradients-object-detection/) to detect the objects.

Comment: Thank you much! I will give a try
But if you could help my issue, regarding to features comparision that would be great

Comment: Shawan I am trying to use ORB algorithm using anaconda, but the package is not there. Even though the openCv is installed
Can you please help to install ORB in conda

Comment: This seems like it should be another question. Opencv should already have orb in it. It is not installed separately. Are you using `orb= cv2.ORB()` from the tutorials. What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I just tried your example. Not good results to be honest. The algorithms always matches something, like this: http://imgur.com/a/qLGwh
I just need boolean answer if match or not, and seems always getting yes((

Comment: May be there is a way to count the number of matches and if they are less, than it is not match. Just dont know how to do that